# Accessing a context created with useContext in a class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I asked this question how to expose a function from React to the outside HTML:
[Use React in CMS and expose functions to HTML to access useState functions in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936167/use-react-in-cms-and-expose-functions-to-html-to-access-usestate-functions-in-re)
Because I couldn't find a pure functional solution for this, I tried it with class, because in class there is 'this' which I can bind to window.

```
import React from 'react';
import MyContext from '../context/Context';

class Api extends React.Component{
    static contexType = MyContext;

    constructor(){
        super();
        window.api = this;
    }

    exposed(value){
       let c = this.context;
       console.log("value", value)
       console.log(c.number);
       //c.setNumber({...number, "n1": value})
    }

    render(){
        return(null);
    }
}

export default Api;
```

And in the CMS template I defined this input field:

```
<input type="number" onchange="window.api.exposed(this.value)" />
```

The onchange works and calls exposed() and gives me the actual value. However c.number is always undefined and c is an empty object.

The context works fine in the functional component where it is in Context.js defined as

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createContext({});
```

Api component get's inserted in App.js like this:

```
function App() {
      return (
        <ContextProvider>
            <Api />
        </ContextProvider>
  );
}
```

And the context provider has a number state variable:

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState({"n1": 0, "n2": 1});
```

And puts it on the context:

```
return(
    <MyContext.Provider value={{
        number
    }}>
        <div className="contextProvider">
            {props.children}
        </div>
    </MyContextContext.Provider>
);
```

Why can't I access the context from the class component?

Comment: Can you share an example of how you're trying to access the context from the class component? Right now, you're only demonstrated how you are providing the context, not consuming it.

Comment: No, it was a stupid typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static contexType = MyContext;
```

missing a 't'

```
static contextType = MyContext;
```